# Java quickly draw image

Tags: java, colors, paint

I have a BufferedImage which has a color model type of IndexColorModel.  When I try and paint this image using Graphics2D.drawImage() it takes about 30 milliseconds.  However, if I first convert this image to a DirectColorModel it only takes about 3 milliseconds to paint.  In order to do this conversion I call

```
AffineTransformOp identityOp = new AffineTransformOp(new AffineTransform(), AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
displayImage = identityOp.filter(displayImage, null);
```

This converts the displayImage from an IndexColorModel to a DirectColorModel.  However, this process takes about 25 milliseconds.

My question is either how do I paint an IndexColorModel image faster or quickly convert to another ColorModel that I can paint faster?

Thanks